# Laravel, Only one row for day

Tags: laravel

I'm studing my database logging organizzation and I have some question to solve,

I get sensor data every 5minutes, after 7 day I create an avarge in block of 30minutes

And that's is ok, my idea was storing data as:

| Date | Avarage Sensor | Maximum of the day | Minimum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 01/01/2021 00:00 | 13.2 | 15.2 | 10.2 |
| 01/01/2021 00:30 | 14.1 | 15.2 | 10.2 |
| etc | etc.. | etc.. | etc.. |
| 02/01/2021 00:00 | 12.2 | 16.7 | 9.1 |
| 02/01/2021 00:30 | 15.1 | 16.7 | 9.1 |

How can I acces to all max and min for each day in the faster way for each day??

Something like: for each days between $day1 $day2 select max and min only one (for each day)

Alternative is creating another table with only max and min

Answer (score 0):

Your column naming was not standard, so i assumed the naming conventions.

> How can I access to all max and min for each day in the faster way for each day??

Simply query the data, `whereDate()` helper from the query builder. You need to have Eloquent models defined for this to work.

```
$sensorData = Sensor::whereDate('recorded_at', Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', '11-06-2021'))
    ->get();
```

Now you can access the data like so.

```
foreach ($sensorData as $data) {
    // now you have all your mix and max data
    $data->min_value;
    $data->max_value;
}
```

---

> Something like: for each days between $day1 $day2 select max and min
> only one (for each day)

Use `SQL` group by and aggregation.

```
$sensorData = Sensor::groupBy(DB::raw('date(recorded_at) as recorded_at'))
    ->select('recorded_at', DB::raw('max(max_value) as max_value'), DB::raw('min(min_value) as min_value'))
    ->get();
```

Now the data would present itself like this. Grouped data is not for saving, as you overwrite values in the model, with the aggregated values. Perfect for showing your data thou.

```
foreach ($sensorData as $data) {
    // now it would be grouped by days
    $data->recorded_at;
    $data->min_value;
    $data->max_value;
}
```

---

These above points indicate that your data structure is fine. I think the best approach would be to separate sensor readings from the sensor and let SQL calculate the min and maxs on the fly.

I would imagine the structure could look like this.

`sensors` table

```
id | name
```

`readings` table

```
id | sensor_id | recorded_at | recorded_value
```

Instead of calculating minimum and averages beforehand, let `SQL` handle this when you request the data. This can be a performance problems in enormous systems, but ran similar on a production system with a fair amount of data without any troubles.

Comment: I would avoid `whereDate` as the column index is not used with the derived value from the SQL `DATE()` function. Something like `whereBetween('recorded_at', [now()->startOfDay(), now()->endOfDay()])` allows use of indexes.

Comment: (Although information provided by OP doesn't even make clear whether or not it's a date column.)